# Launch Configuration question (AWS Certified Solutions Architect – Associate Certification)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

You can see the question and answer given by others. **My question is why not C, C also seems correct.**

```
Which of the following statements is true of creating a launch configuration using an EC2 instance?
A.  The launch configuration can be created only using the Query APIs.
B.  Auto Scaling automatically creates a launch configuration directly from an EC2 instance.
C.  A user should manually create a launch configuration before creating an Auto Scaling group.
D.  The launch configuration should be created manually from the AWS CLI.
```

Answer: B

You can create an Auto Scaling group directly from an EC2 instance. When you use this feature. Auto Scaling automatically creates a launch configuration for you as well. Reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/create-lc-with-instancelD.html

Answer (score 1):

That's a really poor question. I would recommend spending your time elsewhere rather than trying to diagnose this question.

I suspect the question is also pretty old because Auto Scaling groups can now also accept Launch Templates, and the link you provided doesn't work. (The updated link is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-lc-with-instanceID.html)

Questions that use "should" are not well-written. Exam questions are trying to test your knowledge of how to do something successfully, not how you "should" do something. For example, questions would normally ask for the lowest-cost solution or a solution with the highest availability, leaving no questions about the correct answer.

To answer your question:

- A Launch Configuration can be created in the management console, via the AWS CLI or via AWS SDK API calls (so C and D are valid and A is incorrect)
- It is *not* possible to create a Launch Configuration from an existing Amazon EC2 instance (so B is incorrect)
- It is now possible to create a **Launch Template** from an existing Amazon EC2 instance, and this can be used by an Auto Scaling group (but this isn't what they asked)

**Bottom line:** Let the author know that the question is outdated/incorrect.